# Using ptrepack to reclaim deleted nodes in hdf5 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytables

I have written a bunch of pandas DataFrames to a h5 file using the Pytables integration in pandas. Since then I've deleted some of the groups in the h5 file and I want to repack it in order to reclaim the space. From what I've found I know I need to use the Pytables `ptrepack` tool. However I can't get it to work. Can someone let me know if I'm messing something up in my script or if I'm actually running across a bug in pytables? If I am messing it up can you give me an example for importing, and calling ptrepack to simply repack a h5 file in order to save space?

Here's my script and the errors I get:

[image: error when running ptrepack]

When I looked at the ptrepack.py script in the pytables folder in anaconda I also saw that I should be able to pass a help flag to it.. but that's also not working. Here's the error I get when I try get the help flag to work

[image: help flag error]

Currently I'm working on a windows 10 machine
with the following package versions:
python 3.5.1
pytables: 3.2.2
pandas: 0.18.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, firstly, to get the help dialog to show in the command prompt you have to do either `ptrepack -h` or `ptrepack --help`
I didn't manage to get the script working in python as it seems it has been made specially for the command line- I did however find this very helpful notebook on the subject ([Reclaiming HDF5 Space][1]) which have the following solution

```
from subprocess import call
outfilename = 'out.h5'
command = ["ptrepack", "-o", "--chunkshape=auto", "--propindexes", filename, outfilename]
call(command)
```

Note that this essentially just starts a subprocess which calls the repack function.
[1]: https://github.com/jackdotwa/python-concepts/blob/master/hdf5/reclaiming_space.ipynb "Reclaiming HDF5 space"